# IBM Informix - cast decimal to time format

Tags: informix

My customer uses an IBM Informix environment to track production information. In the current SharePoint 2013 he was able to show those infos with this query:

```
Select  stillst_grund,sum(charge_bis-charge_von) from mstillstand
where firma=1
and month(anfertigungsdat)=month(date(sysdate))
and year(anfertigungsdat)=year(date(sysdate))
and arbplatznr=2
group by 1
```

The OleDB connection was used for this. Unfortunately, the new SharePoint 2019 seems to miss some drivers so we switched over ODBC driver. The statement above is the only one which makes trouble. The other two dozen are working quite fine.
Meanwhile, I found, that the sum()-function (or maybe the subtraction inside of it) is causing this trouble.

Some background info to this statement: It simply shows the machine name and the duration (in format %d %HH:%mm:%ss) of its time standing still.

Besides fixing the sum()-issue there might be another solution. I found another column called charge_still. This column gives me a decimal(8,4) and seems to be the difference between charge_bis and charge_von:

```
Select stillst_grund, charge_still AS Ausgangswert from mstillstand
where firma=1
and month(anfertigungsdat)=month(date(sysdate))
and year(anfertigungsdat)=year(date(sysdate))
and arbplatznr=2
group by 1,2
```

What would you say makes more sense: Fix the first statement with the sum() or convert/cast the charge_still? Until now I didn't find a handy solution to convert a decimal to the mentioned format...

Comment: Which informix version are you using? What are the types of the columns involved? What type of data is sharepoint expecting?

Comment: Hi Luís, it's version 12.10.0000 FC10WE. charge_von and charge_bis are datetime (year to second), charge_still is a decimal (8,4) and stillst_grund is a varchar(15).
For SharePoint it doesn't matter which type is coming in. In doubt everything would be stored as line of text. In former SharePoint environment it worked with the OleDB driver. Now we need to use the ODBC driver (maybe the installed frameworks required by SharePoint doesn't support OleDB anymore; I don't know).

Comment: The data type that results from the subtraction is an `INTERVAL`. If I am properly interpreting the documentation, the `OleDB` driver converts `INTERVAL` into a string type. The `ODBC` driver does not convert into a string type, it also returns an `INTERVAL` type. So you can try to cast the `INTERVAL` into a `VARCHAR` and see if that solves your issue: `SUM( charge_bis - charge_von )::VARCHAR( 25 )` .

Comment: Luís, you're my little hero. Unfortunately I can't vote your comment up due to my current reputation... Your guess is a great solution.